# Programmatically get the number of the incoming call

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How can I programmatically get the number of the incoming call from Background application ?

Comment: Please mark the answer that helped you the most as accepted.

Answer (score 7):

You cannot do this.

Apps running in the background can **only** do the following things: continue on something that won't last too long, play music or store current state in background.

*Would you like it if one of your apps that you had been using picked up a phonenumber that called you and posted it on the internet? That may be one of the reasons why apple doesn't allow this…*

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid there is no way to access that information. I believe it would be a security risk for apple to give developers access to such information.

Comment: I also think that this is not possible.

Answer (score 3):

if it's ok that such app will use private API(=forget about AppStore for this app) - you can see comments to [How can I use private APIs to block incoming calls in an iOS application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7326338/how-can-i-use-private-apis-to-block-incoming-calls-in-an-ios-application/8337642#8337642)
without private APIs - no way.