# How to get incoming call phone number?

Tags: iphone, phone-call, core-telephony

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Programmatically get the number of the incoming call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4003791/programmatically-get-the-number-of-the-incoming-call)

Is it possible to get the incoming call number in iphone using any private api?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do this.That will be a security risk.

Comment: Hi Manoj, thanks for your reply. Can you tell me if i am using jailbroken iphone then also it is not possible?