# How can I use private APIs to block incoming calls in an iOS application?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-telephony

I would like to be able to selectively block incoming calls in an iOS application I'm writing.  This is intended for personal use, not the App Store, so I'm fine with using private APIs to accomplish this.

I have recently come across the Core Telephony framework.  Is there a way to use this framework to block calls?  If not, what private APIs could I use to do this?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Are you sure it does not?
code examples on http://tech.ruimaninfo.com/?p=83 shows how to do such things.
Core Telephony headers in SDK are not complete.
Of course this means no app store
this is my code fragment based on example I linked

```
if ([str1 isEqualToString:@"kCTCallIdentificationChangeNotification"])
{
    NSDictionary *info = (__bridge NSDictionary *)userInfo;
    CTCall2 *call = (__bridge CTCall *)[info objectForKey:@"kCTCall"];
    NSString *caller = CTCallCopyAddress(NULL, call);
    NSLog(@"Caller %@",caller);
    if ([caller isEqualToString:@"+1555665753"])
    {
       //disconnect this call
       CTCallDisconnect(call);

}
```

additional definitions needed:

```
typedef struct __CTCall CTCall;
extern NSString *CTCallCopyAddress(void*, CTCall *);
extern void CTCallDisconnect(CTCall*);
```

and you need to monitor telephony center's callback(see linked example)
I tested this fragment on my iOS5 device

Comment: I no I can't put it in on the App Store but how would I block a specific number using that link?

Comment: Not yet, I don't see any changes :/

Comment: Niceeee. I honestly think you get at least 10 up votes over the next few months since that code is very helpful! One last thing, how would I keep the app running so that, that code you posted is called whenever I get a call even if the app is closed?

Comment: strictly speaking you can't - apple rules. but looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4656214/iphone-backgrounding-to-poll-for-events and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7610182/is-it-legal-to-create-a-recursive-background-handler-in-iphoneprocessing-when can give you some ideas. one thing I encountered - you better keep CoreLocation active and not in SignificantLocationMonitoring mode(even with 3km accuracy) or you could be terminated too fast. Of course you must measure battery usage issues(after all you use CoreLocation),etc

Comment: you sure? I know iBlacklist and MCaller do it that way but they have the phone JB'ed. Are you positive that there is no way?

Comment: enter pressed too fast. see my edited comment. there is way, but tricky(you have to play by apple rules here)

Comment: If it doesn't then I want to know how is this 360安全卫士  app doing it？ check it guys

Comment: itunes link to 360 app please

Comment: Does anybody have any urls of  code source example as the web site http://tech.ruimaninfo.com/?p=83 isn't responding. I want to be able to determine the incoming number

Answer (score 3):

Core Telephony doesn't support this.  To my knowledge there is no way to do this with any known private APIs either.

Comment: How does iBlackList and MCaller do it then?

Comment: @H2CO3, where did I say "It's impossible"?

Comment: @GregMartin "To my knowledge there is no way to do this with any known private APIs either."

Comment: @H2CO3, I don't believe those two statements are equal.  I also wonder why it matters on a 1.5 year old question that has an accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

Since iOS 10.0+ there is CallKit which includes a Call Blocking and Identification API: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/callkit

(Information for people which find this in 2020 or in the future)