# Create a call block list app for jailbroken iphone

Tags: iphone, cydia, callblocking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I use private APIs to block incoming calls in an iOS application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7326338/how-can-i-use-private-apis-to-block-incoming-calls-in-an-ios-application)

Can anybody help me to create block list of calls for jailbroken ios devices?

Is there any private APIs are available for creating block list?

Thanks

Comment: nothing...I am looking for an opinion and what is starting point?

Answer (score 1):

See [How can I use private APIs to block incoming calls in an iOS application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7326338/how-can-i-use-private-apis-to-block-incoming-calls-in-an-ios-application)

I haven't tried it myself, but the accepted answer and the link provided (http://tech.ruimaninfo.com/?p=83) should answer your question.