# iOS - private API - accept incoming phone call

Tags: ios

Is it possible to accept/answer an incoming phone call programmatically via a private API?

I tried out the code to block an incoming call referenced at [How can I use private APIs to block incoming calls in an iOS application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7326338/how-can-i-use-private-apis-to-block-incoming-calls-in-an-ios-application/8337642#8337642). Eventually, I got it to build for iOS 6.

Maybe one difficulty is that the own app goes to the background as soon as a call arrives? Or is there an event the app can receive before that?

Answer (score 1):

I got it: You have to use `CTCallAnswer(call);` in the following notification case:

```
if ([str1 isEqualToString:@"kCTCallIdentificationChangeNotification"])
{
    NSDictionary *info = (__bridge NSDictionary *)userInfo;
    CTCall2 *call = (__bridge CTCall *)[info objectForKey:@"kCTCall"];
    NSString *caller = CTCallCopyAddress(NULL, call);
    NSLog(@"Caller %@",caller);

    // answer this call
    CTCallAnswer(call);
}
```