# Is it possible to answer a call programmatically in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone

Is it possible to programmatically answer a call in iPhone? I have already googled about this and found that iOS SDK does not support such feature. But I found an answering machine app in Appstore.

https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/prank-answering-machine-free/id508457142?mt=8

Please help me out.

Comment: Have you tried it, does it work? The app i mean.

Comment: I have downloaded the free version of that app.. but it was not working fine. I have tested using my old iPhone 3GS

Comment: you can perform this by DispatchQueue with 0.1 seconds delay and answer the call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say it depends. If you want to make a app and publish it in app store, its not possible. However if you want don't want to publish on app store and willing to use private api, then its possible. Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14340497/ios-private-api-accept-incoming-phone-call) answer.

Comment: So app should be an enterprise app right? One more question is it possible to record a call using 3rd party API??

Comment: Yes its an enterprise app. To the best of my knowledge, recording is not possible but have never explored as I never had a requirement. If I answered your original question, please accept/upvote.

Answer (score 7):

No this is not possible, the iOS SDK does not allow any interaction with the phone.app.

Also the app you have found is a prank app, one that you start if you receive a call and the play back one the messages from the app.

Comment: so the user has to attend the call first?right? App wont attend the call??

Comment: @kunjus Yes that is right, you just answer a call and play back a one of the sounds. It's just a soundboard.

Answer (score 2):

No, that is not possible. The CoreTelephony framework lets your application receive notifications if there is any change in the call state, but there is no way to answer it.
The app that you mentioned does not say anything about answering a call, from what I can see.