# CTCallCopyAddress - "Undefined symbols for architecture armv7"

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-telephony, undefined-symbol

*Firstly - I am developing a jailbreak tweak, hence the use private APIs.*

I am following the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7326338/how-can-i-use-private-apis-to-block-incoming-calls-in-an-ios-application/8337642#8337642) however, I'm getting the following compiler error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
"CTCallCopyAddress(void*, CTCall*)", referenced from:
  telephonyEventCallback(__CFNotificationCenter*, void*, __CFString const*, void const*, __CFDictionary const*) in MyCode.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

When I have encountered similar warnings/errors before it was due to missing out libraries in the build phases. Yet, I have checked that CoreTelephony.framework is added. Does anyone have any pointers as to where I am going wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: What version of iOS are you using? This seems to be perfectly available on iOS 5.1, for example.

Comment: iOS 6.1 - that would make sense. Do you know what I would have to change/add for support with iOS 6.0 +?

Comment: I don't know, frankly. Use "nm" to find out if it's available on iOS 6.1

Answer (score 0):

Are you using this code in obj-c or obj-c++ code? If it's latter then you need to define it like this `extern "C" NSString* CTCallCopyAddress(void*, CTCall*)`. I use this API on iOS 6 and never had any problems.