# Get incoming call information programmatically in iOS7

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

Can we get incoming call information(number) programmatically in iOS7?

I want to create an application so that at the time of any incoming call, my application cuts the call and sends a text message to that number.

Comment: if this is for AppStore release, no you can not. Apple does not allow you to get any details about the call, like the phone number. Especial in the background.

Answer (score 0):

Read this may be helpfull, Because in this user blocking calls according to number. where you can check your number [How can I use private APIs to block incoming calls in an iOS application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7326338/how-can-i-use-private-apis-to-block-incoming-calls-in-an-ios-application/8337642#8337642)
In this user getting info of incoming calls

Answer (score 0):

There is a [hack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7326338/how-can-i-use-private-apis-to-block-incoming-calls-in-an-ios-application/8337642#8337642) for this but you can't publish to the AppStore with it.

You can only use this in ad-hoc applications.