# Unable to build iOS 7 app with entitlement

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, entitlements, code-signing-entitlements

I'm trying to build a phone-blocker app using CoreTelephony private API,
It is for my own use so I don't care about App Store.

I've used the code that was linked to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7326338/how-can-i-use-private-apis-to-block-incoming-calls-in-an-ios-application)

I've then found another forum thread that suggested that for using CTCall, CTCallDisconnect, etc. functions on iOS 7, I need to add the entitlement 'com.apple.coretelephony.Calls.allow'

My problem is that I can't get this to run on my device when using the entitlement above.
I've managed to get it to run without the entitlement, but of curse, the above functions didn't worked. I was able to get info about incoming calls, but couldn't block or make any outgoing call myself using those functions,
But the code itself was able to use the private API to receive information about the incoming call.

When trying to build to my device, directly from Xcode, when adding the required entitlement, I'm getting the following error message:
"The entitlements specified in your application's Code Signing Entitlements file do not match those specified in your provisioning profile."

I've tried googling the above error but haven't encountered any solution that actually worked for me.
I think that maybe this is because I'm adding an entitlement manually, and not thru the 'allowed' entitlements in Xcode's capabilities menu.

I've also tried to use Xcode to 'archive' it to a general iOS device,
and also to build without signing the app and creating entitlement xml file manually and then using terminal's codesign to sign the code with the entitlement.
While using both of the solutions above I've managed to get an signed, with entitlement, app,
But when copying it to my device (using iTunes) the app would finish Installing, and the app icon would remain grey, and whenever I click on it it would just say 'Installing...'
So I haven't been able to actually run it on my device.

My device is NOT jailbroken, iPhone 4s, iOS 7.1.2.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Pleease did you get a solution for this?

Comment: No.....:-/.....But if I would, I would post it here. I'll appreciate if you will find a solution before me, you'll post it here as well.