# Identify number of incoming call in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios5

How do I know who is calling me?
Identify the number or even the contact in my list case I have.

I can identify if have or not a call, with this code.

```
void (^ctCallStateMuda)(NSNotification *) = ^(NSNotification * notification) {
    NSString *callInfo = [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:@"callState"];
    if ([callInfo isEqualToString:CTCallStateIncoming]) {
        NSLog(@">>>>>> chegando");
    } else if ([callInfo isEqualToString:CTCallStateConnected])  {
        NSLog(@">>> atendendo <<<");        
    }  else if ([callInfo isEqualToString:CTCallStateDisconnected])  {
        NSLog(@"desconectado >>>>>>");        
    } else if ([callInfo isEqualToString:CTCallStateConnected])  {
        NSLog(@"discando");        
    } else {
        NSLog(@"nada");        
    }
};

CTCallCenter *callCenter;
callCenter = [[CTCallCenter alloc] init];
callCenter.callEventHandler = ^(CTCall* aCallIncomming) {
    NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:aCallIncomming.callState
                                                     forKey:@"callState"];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"CTCallStateDidChange"
                                                        object:self
                                                      userInfo:dict];
};

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:@"CTCallStateDidChange" 
                                                  object:nil 
                                                   queue:nil 
                                              usingBlock:ctCallStateMuda];
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Programmatically get the number of the incoming call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4003791/programmatically-get-the-number-of-the-incoming-call)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have access to this information in the public SDK (a jailbroken iPhone is another matter). Apple prohibit apps from having access to *any* information relating to call history. The code you've posted above is so your app can detect when the user is receiving a phone call and adapt their interface accordingly, but that's it.